# Getting a 404 error on a page that was accessible

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have created a data scraper to scrape pricing data from a website. It was working like a charm
until one day it stopped working.

```
page = requests.get(url)   #url is the url of the page I am scraping
contents = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser') 
#start parsing the page using BeautifulSoup
```

Now I am getting a http 404 error message when requests.get(url) is executed. I know the page is there because the URL can be accessed from the browser.

I am pretty certain added security was added to allow restricted access to the url.
Is there a way to get past the 404 message?

Comment: Look at `page.text` and debug from there.

Comment: Can you share page's url?

Comment: Here is the page URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NXPI/options?p=NXPI&date=1629417600

Comment: Page.text is a 404 return message  in html format. <!-- Not Found on Server -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and I didn't get any error so I think this is about your user_agent. Try it like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NXPI/options?p=NXPI&date=1629417600&guccounter=1"

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = bs(page,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```